# To show that function $f$ is not injective.

Tags: functions

Let $\Bbb N=\{1,2,3,\cdots\}$. How to show that functions $f, g:\Bbb N\times\Bbb N\to\Bbb N$ defined by $f(m, n) =m^2+n^3, g(m,n) =m^2n^3$ are not injective?If I consider integers over natural numbes then very easy to show not injective because of square term. I even have no general idea that why these functions are not injective. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: I encourage you to try to find more examples beyond those given below.  A big part of growing as a mathematician is developing the ability to be creative and be able to find examples and counterexamples on your own.  There are infinitely many examples that you can show why these functions are not injective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(2^3,1) = 1+2^6 = f(1,2^2)$ and $g(2^3,1) = 2^6 = g(1,2^2)$ so neither are injective

Comment: zero is not a natural number .

Comment: @neelkanth there are multiple standard definitions of natural numbers—the asker didn't make it clear which they chose.

Comment: @Kenta S edited. Thank you.

Comment: Edited the answer as well

Comment: @SolubleFish Thank you very much.